# Run a RAM speed test

Tags: memory, speed

Is there any way to test the actual speed of the RAM to know how many gigabytes per second it transfers data? I'm on a Windows machine, so solutions based on that would be nice, but if there is something for Linux I can also work with that. I know my RAM speed is PC2666, but I would like to know the GB/s speed on my machine.

Comment: What will you achieve?   Designers put in memory matched to the computer.  If you could put in faster memory you are not likely to see a performance increase.

Comment: Max Transfer Rate is static for all DDR4 chips of a given speed. Your transfer speed will be 21333.33MB/s or so. That is intrinsic in being compatible with DDR4 PC2666. Also note that in real world scenarios, Max Transfer Rate is not the end-all-be-all of RAM statistics. Frequency is probably the more important (and drives Transactions-per-second, which is what Max Transfer Rate is calculated from).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_DDR4_module

Comment: [Memtest86+](https://www.memtest.org/) will report some actual performance/throughput numbers of the PC memory system before it runs the pattern diagnostics.  It has to execute in place of any OS when you boot the PC.  Often available as part of a Linux distro install image.